# RSpec: Test if partial associated with model renders

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have a group of Models (say ModelA, ModelB, ModelC....) which all need to have an associated partial.  Namely:

views/model_as/_model_a.xml.haml
views/model_bs/_model_b.xml.haml
 
views/model_cs/_model_c.xml.haml ...

So that an instance of these models can be rendered as xml...

```
model_a = ModelA.last
render model_a
```

I already have a shared test for each model so I can call

```
it_behaves_like 'group model', ModelA.new
```

from my model spec, to test other shared features of these models.

I am wanting to write a spec

```
it 'should render as xml'
```

and put it in the *shared_examples_for 'group model'*

I realize this is mixing a view spec in with the model spec, which seems like its a bad idea.  On the other hand, I am testing something associated with each model rather than some particular view template.

My questions:

- Is this a bad idea?
- If its not a bad idea, how do I create this test?  `render model_a` throws a *undefined method `render'* error.
- If it is a bad idea, where would you put these tests?

Answer (score 0):

I've decided it is indeed a bad idea.  In the end I moved it to a view spec.

Ultimately this made more sense, not only because it properly treated views in view specs, but because it allowed me to check all the rendering features of the models in one place -- rather than spread out through a bunch of model specs.

Now that I've done it I am not sure why this path wasn't obvious from the beginning, but just incase someone else is asking themselves the same question I'll paste in my initial implementation as an example:

## spec/views/angelxml/angel_views_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

module Angelxml
  describe "angel views" do
    it_behaves_like 'angel view', Message.new
    it_behaves_like 'angel view', Question.new
    it_behaves_like 'angel view', Transfer.new
    it_behaves_like 'angel view', Voicemail.new

    it_behaves_like 'angel view', AngelAction.new, "action"
    it_behaves_like 'angel view', CcExp.new, "ccexp"
    it_behaves_like 'angel view', Comment.new
    it_behaves_like 'angel view', CreditCard.new, "creditcard"
    it_behaves_like 'angel view', Currency.new, nil, true
    it_behaves_like 'angel view', Date.new, nil, true
    it_behaves_like 'angel view', ErrorStrategy.new
    it_behaves_like 'angel view', Goto.new, nil, true
    it_behaves_like 'angel view', Invalid.new, nil, true
    it_behaves_like 'angel view', Keyword.new
    it_behaves_like 'angel view', Link.new, nil, true
    it_behaves_like 'angel view', NoLink.new, "no"
    it_behaves_like 'angel view', Number.new
    it_behaves_like 'angel view', Play.new
    it_behaves_like 'angel view', Prompt.new
    it_behaves_like 'angel view', Response.new
    it_behaves_like 'angel view', Time.new, nil, true
    it_behaves_like 'angel view', Valid.new
    it_behaves_like 'angel view', Var.new, nil, true
    it_behaves_like 'angel view', VariableList.new, "variables"
    it_behaves_like 'angel view', YesLink.new, "yes"
    it_behaves_like 'angel view', YesNo.new
  end
end
```

## spec/support/shared_examples_for_angel_view

```
shared_examples_for 'angel view' do |angel_model,node_name,no_close_tag|

  it 'model should render as xml' do
    model_name = angel_model.class.name.demodulize
    model = FactoryGirl.build(model_name.underscore.to_sym)
    node_name = model_name if node_name.nil?
    node_name = node_name.upcase

    render model
    response.body.should include("<"+node_name)
    response.body.should include("</"+node_name+">") unless no_close_tag
  end

end
```